# concatenate .csv files within subfolders and adding all into one .csv file

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, frame, glob

I have .csv files that are inside the folder (months) and then inside multiple folders. I am trying to concatenate all those files into one .csv file

for eg. inside Jan there are 20 folders and each of the folders has a .csv file.

January

folder1   inside (.csv file)

folder2   inside (.csv file)

folder3   inside (.csv file)

...

folder50  inside (.csv file)

till December

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

path = r"C:\Users\Desktop\AB_Met\2019\Jan" #using in windows 10
arr = os.listdir(path)
all_files = []  # list of all the data files that need to merge

for i in arr:
    all_files = all_files + glob.glob(path + "**/.csv", recursive=True)
    
li = []  # list for files as pandas dataframes

for filename in all_files:
    frame = pd.read_csv(filename)  
    li.append(frame)

frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)  # concatanate all separate dataframes into one dataframe
print(frame)
```

Comment: What is the issue here?

Comment: Hello, sorry I was editing my question. Here I have mentioned it clearly. Thanks for reaching

Comment: why write to a `.txt` file?  what format, why not just keep things in CSV?

Comment: yeah I want it in .csv only. its a mistake. Sorry

Comment: its gives no object to concatenate error

Comment: The pattern you are using to get `.csv` files in glob is wrong. It should be `path + r"\**\*.csv" instead of `path + "**/.csv"`

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) rather than `os` and `glob`.

It has a [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) operation makes these sorts of operations relatively simple, something like:

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

def iterate_over_csv_files(root):
    for path in root.glob("**/*.csv"):
        yield pd.read_csv(path)

root = Path(r"C:\Users\Desktop\AB_Met\2019")

df = pd.concat(iterate_over_csv_files(root / 'Jan'))

df.to_csv("2019-01.csv", index=False)
```

would grab everything from the `Jan` directory and put it into a single big dataframe, and write it out to a single CSV file.

Comment: Well for some months it shows an error: No columns to parse from file.

Comment: maybe put a `try`/`catch` block around the `read_csv` call and print out the `path`s it fails for.  that should help you investigating issues with your data

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

path = Path(r"C:\Users\Desktop\AB_Met\2019") # directory to traverse
dfs = [pd.read_csv(f) for f in path.glob("**/*.csv")]  # list for files as pandas dataframes
frame = pd.concat(dfs, axis=0, ignore_index=True)  # concatanate all dataframes

print(frame)
```

This code loops through all the `.csv` files in `path`, creates list of dataframes using `pd.read_csv()`, and then concatenates the list of dataframes using `pd.concat()`

Comment: this isn't working! It gives an error: No object to concatenate.

Comment: What does `list(path.glob("**/*.csv"))` give you?